# Will I lose any Principal if I cash in a CD early?

Tags: united-states, certificate-of-deposit

I've had a 35 month CD for 11 months and thinking about cashing it in now. Will I lose any principal if I cash it out now or would it vary by institution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory, it would depend on the institution.  You'd need to see what your institution's policies were.

In practice, I've never seen an early withdrawal penalty that was anything other than some number of months of accrued interest (depending on the term of the CD).

Answer (score 1):

> I've had a 35 month CD for 11 months and thinking about cashing it in
> now. Will I lose any principal if I cash it out now or would it vary
> by institution?

Go back to the documents you received when you purchased the CD. You can contact the directly.

In general you will be faced with a penalty of x months of interest. If you cashed in before you help the CD for those X moths the penalty would be greater than the amount of interest you earned so far. Because your are 11 months in you are probably safe.

Still check with the place you bought the CD.

Not only does it depend n the institution, it can even depend on the exact terms of the CD you purchased. Some banks offer multiple flavors of CDs each with a different set of terms. Some give you the ability to add money, others allow you to bump up the interest rate.